# Node.js call function form the node CMD with arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use the code below to call a function written in a javascript file, this does call the function, however it does not give arguments along with it:

to call the function FROM THE CMD I type "foo"

```
var readline = require('readline');

global.foo = function foo (data) {
  console.log("foo was called " + data);
}

process.stdin.on("data", function(input) {
  // don't forget to call .trim() to remove the \n
  var fn = input.toString().trim();

  // function exists
  if (fn in global && typeof global[fn] === "function") {
    global[fn]();
  }

  // function does not exist
  else {
    console.log("could not find " + fn + " function");
  }
});
process.stdin.resume();
```

Comment: What arguments do you expect it to pass? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround:

```
var readline = require('readline');

process.stdin.on("data", function(input){
    var fn = input.toString().trim();
    var command = fn.split(' ')[0];
    var args = fn.substr(fn.indexOf(' ') + 1);
    if (command == "foo"){
        console.log(args);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

type `global.foo(data)` instead.

And change foo to this:

```
global.foo = function(data) {
  console.log("foo was called " + data);
};
```

If you don't want to use global.foo then add this line:

```
var foo = global.foo;
```

Then at the end of your code add this to call it with arguments from the command line

```
foo(process.argv[0]);
```

And from the command line

```
Node <file> <argument>
```

Comment: this causes it to not find function foo

Comment: foo or global.foo? This should work fine, I've just run this on my machine. See my edit if you just want to use foo.

Comment: and how did you call the function?

Comment: if i type 'foo', it calls the function, id i type 'foo test', i get could not find the foo function.

Comment: I called it using `global.foo("hello")`. If I wanted to use a variable instead I'd add `var data = "hello";` to the file (or run that line of code inside node) then type `global.foo(data)`.

Comment: i am trying to call this from the cmd window?

Comment: Ah, ok. You need to use process.argv[...] to get arguments passed in from the command line. See my updates.

Comment: could you point me to an example please, I  will also update the question, Thanks

Comment: How do i go about using? "Node <file> <argument>" the script is running i just want to call a function and send an argument with it?

Comment: OK here is a fiddle to demonstrate what I think your code should look like and what you need to do inside node when it is running with the script loaded: http://jsfiddle.net/GarryPas/t9kx4x7o/2/

Comment: thanks but still could not find the foo(data) function and i did define data as the fiddle shows